# How to Implement Image recognition system in Website using Django?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, image-recognition, vs-web-site-project

I have made an image recognition system using python and I am trying to implement that in website. I have have a system that recognizes the fruit images built using CNN. Now, I have built a website which is of a Fruit-blog. I want a section or a page in in that website in which a user can upload an image and the website can recognize which fruit is the given image of but I have no idea how to implement my recognition system in the website. Can you please help me explaining what to do and how can I implement the AI from python to Django website?

Comment: What exactly you could not implement in Django? We need some code here and more info...

Answer (score 0):

The main part comes from freezing your model and serving it using a web framework like flask or django. Then you can communicate with it by passing images and receiving prediction objects. An example is at this github repo written in Django for deploy in Heroku https://github.com/marcogdepinto/Deep-learning-model-deploy-with-django